# Database missing extensions:tym_system_time,quantile orange widget error

Tags: orange

I'm working with the orange data mining tool. In most of the examples data  taken from files or google sheets links but in the blog [link](http://blog.biolab.si/2015/10/19/sql-for-orange/) they given that we can take data from postgresql database tables also but when follow the steps of blog I'm getting error.I attached the screen shots of error.

[image]

[image]

I need help in solving this error.

Comment: Looks like this error: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1501 You need those Postgre add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a proper place to ask questions about software issues, but rather about data mining concepts.

However, I'll answer your question.
Your database is missing both extensions as specified in the error message. [Here](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/wiki/Installation-of-PostgreSQL-extensions) are some brief instructions.

Comment: Not a proper place? Interesting. Because it [says on the Orange website](http://orange.biolab.si/community/) to ask Orange GUI-related questions on DS.SE. What other discussion forum or mailing list is more appropriate for this kind of questions?

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by 'GUI-related questions'. I interpret it as workflow construction. Do you interpret it as bugs and issues?

Comment: Is what Dilip Bobby is asking about above a bug? Where do all other questions belong or, IOW, how does one properly reach the community?

Comment: Ah, never mind — I found it: http://orange.biolab.si/forum/

Comment: My previous comment was a joke, of course. ^D^